# PHP included files - Error on the Production Server

Tags: php, caching, file-upload, dreamweaver, php-include

We've been experiencing an issue with our Intranet on the Production Server:
after performing the upload through Dreamweaver CS6, some web pages with included php files randomly return an error ("cannot find file...")

With a new upload, the error temporarily disappears, but after 1 or 2 days, it shows up again.

We believe that it's a kind of cache error, probably caused by Dreamweaver.

Please notice that everything works perfectly on the Test Server, even though both servers have exactly the same configuration (same PHP version and configuration, same WAMP version and configuration, and so on).

We tried to use the PHP setting: "Cache-Control: no-cache", but it didn't work.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated;
thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Can you connect via FTP and verify that the 'to-be included' files transferred over properly

Comment: Hi Tyler, the Production Server is a local one so we don't even need an FTP connection. By the way, yes, all the files are uploaded properly. Thank you.